# Export arabic message to excel in a ASP.NET websit

Tags: c#, asp.net, arabic

I am having a website which stores some message in arabic .When i try to export it to a csv or excel , it comes as ? . Below  is code which i use to export it

```
public void DownloadCSV(string csvData, string filename)
{
    string strFileName = filename;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strFileName);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-2");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(csvData);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

How can solve this problem . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the ContentEncoding to windows-1256 or utf-8.
Also it's better to use a better library for creating excel files such as http://epplus.codeplex.com/